# Condition "Offset"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Is it possbile to move my "BUY" condition one bar back? Usually, it's showing the signal after the bar is closed but I need this to repaint one bar back. But NOT using the offset.
This idea is for the backtesting purposes only.

I've been googled this but didn't find any info.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned backtest, it sounds like this is a `strategy` and not an `indicator`.

In that case, if you have not already, you could check the option "On bar close".

[image]

If this is checked, market orders will be executed whenever the candle is closed. If unchecked, they will be executed on the open of the next candle.

If this is checked and you still want to move your buy signal one bar back, you cannot do that. You cannot go back in time and buy something.